# mysql query count number of records in main table with multiple attributes in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help building a MYSQL query:

The main table list a persons name and address of vehicle for sale.

The attribute (second) table list the vehicle attributes.

How do I COUNT the number of sellers in the MAIN TABLE where the attribute table COLOR is RED, and YEAR is 2015, and PRICE  less than 15,000 and the customer address is Columbus?

```
select count(`master_id`)
from `customers` c
left join `attributes` a
on c.master_id = a.master_id
where (
a.name = 'color' and a.value = 'red' and 
a.name = 'year' and a.value = '2015' and 
a.name = 'price' and a.value > '15000' and 
c.city = 'Columbus';
```

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Show the table structures.

Comment: You can't expect us to magically know your table structures, table relationship, list of columns in each table.  We are not magician.  Give table structure, input, expected output.  Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select count(*)
from (select master_id
      from `customers` c left join
           `attributes` a
           on c.master_id = a.master_id
      where (name, value) in ( ('color', 'red'), ('year', '2015'), ('price', '15000') and
            c.city = 'Columbus'
      group by a.master_id
      having count(distinct name) = 3
     ) x;
```

Note that this uses tuples to simplify the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the table over and over for each attribute. This makes the joins more complex but the `WHERE` clause is simpler. This query is based on the assumption of your data storage since it is not available in the questions.

```
SELECT COUNT(c.*) 
FROM   `customers` c 
       LEFT JOIN `attributes` aclr 
              ON aclr.name = 'color' 
                 AND c.master_id = aclr.master_id 
       LEFT JOIN `attributes` ayr 
              ON ayr.name = 'year' 
                 AND c.master_id = ayr.master_id 
       LEFT JOIN `attributes` aprc 
              ON aprc.name = 'price' 
                 AND c.master_id = aprc.master_id 
WHERE  aclr.value = 'red' 
       AND ayr.value = '2015' 
       AND aprc.value > '15000' 
       AND c.city = 'Columbus'
GROUP BY c.master_id;
```